# Jquery Datatable - how to refresh the table with some static column (not from backend) by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

I try to use Jquery Datatable.

Firstly, I create a empty datatable :

```
  <script>
      $('#myTable').dataTable();
  </script>

  <table id="myTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
 </table>
```

I want to load the data in the table without refreshing the page by clicking a "refresh" button. 
The refresh button click will trigger an ajax call:

```
function reloadTable(){
      var selectDraftsTable = $("#myTable").DataTable();
      $.ajax ({
          url: "[BACKEND URL]",
          cache: false,
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(json) {
               // clear the data in the table.
                selectDraftsTable.fnClearTable();

               // how to load JSON type of data here??

          }
      });  
  }
```

Here is an example of my data source:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Tiger Nixon",
    "position": "System Architect",
    "salary": "$320,800",
    "start_date": "2011/04/25",
    "office": "Edinburgh",
    "extn": "5421"
  },
  {
    "name": "Garrett Winters",
    "position": "Accountant",
    "salary": "$170,750",
    "start_date": "2011/07/25",
    "office": "Tokyo",
    "extn": "8422"
  },
  {
    "name": "Ashton Cox",
    "position": "Junior Technical Author",
    "salary": "$86,000",
    "start_date": "2009/01/12",
    "office": "San Francisco",
    "extn": "1562"
  },
  {
    "name": "Cedric Kelly",
    "position": "Senior Javascript Developer",
    "salary": "$433,060",
    "start_date": "2012/03/29",
    "office": "Edinburgh",
    "extn": "6224"
  }
]
```

**Question 1:**

How to load these data into the datatable in success function after ajax call?

**Question 2:**

If I have two more special columns in the tables. For example,

```
  <table id="myTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>CheckBox<th>  <!---------- Special column 1 --------->
                <th>Buttons</th>  <!---------- Special column 2 --------->
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
 </table>
```

It should looks something like:

[image]

**The table contains a checkbox column and a button column (button column may contains more than 1 button). I guess I should create these 2 columns when I render the data source because nothing about these 2 special columns is related to backend.

The data source is the same in above. How do I load this data source to the correct columns? and How do I render the checkbox and button in the column after getting those data from ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the reloadTable() function.

```js
var data = [{
  "name": "Tiger Nixon",
  "position": "System Architect",
  "salary": "$320,800",
  "start_date": "2011/04/25",
  "office": "Edinburgh",
  "extn": "5421"
}, {
  "name": "Garrett Winters",
  "position": "Accountant",
  "salary": "$170,750",
  "start_date": "2011/07/25",
  "office": "Tokyo",
  "extn": "8422"
}, {
  "name": "Ashton Cox",
  "position": "Junior Technical Author",
  "salary": "$86,000",
  "start_date": "2009/01/12",
  "office": "San Francisco",
  "extn": "1562"
}, {
  "name": "Cedric Kelly",
  "position": "Senior Javascript Developer",
  "salary": "$433,060",
  "start_date": "2012/03/29",
  "office": "Edinburgh",
  "extn": "6224"
}];

function reloadTable() {
  var selectDraftsTable = $("#myTable").DataTable();
  var i;
  var b = $('<button>Blah!</b>');
  var c = $('<input type="checkbox">');

  // Add new data
  for (i in data) {
    b.attr('id', 'b' + i);
    c.attr('id', 'b' + i);

    // This is the table ( button + checkbox + data values
    selectDraftsTable.row.add(
      [
        b[0].outerHTML,
        c[0].outerHTML
      ].concat(
        Object.keys(data[i]).map(function(k) { return data[i][k]; })
      )
    ).draw();
    
  }
}

reloadTable();
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="myTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Checkbox</th>
      <th>Buttons</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Extn.</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

For the 2nd question, you can insert the button or input field HTML, it will work just like any type of data.

Comment: I tried your codes but the browser said "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined" It looks like selectDraftsTable.row is undefined. Do you know the reason? I am using Datatable 1.9.1.

Comment: I found that table.row is only available since 1.10. In older version, what else can I do to achieve what I want?